# Best Practice for Suscriber and Publisher

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I heard somewhere that the best practice for a node was to create a file receiving and publishing all the message, and then to collect these datas from another file if we need to process them.

Something like this :

process.cpp <===> SuscribeAndPublish.cpp <================================>Node 2
l___________________________________/

Node 1

Sorry for the poor schema ahaha

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277866/best-practice-for-suscriber-and-publisher/) by [StanSmooth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32748/stansmooth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2017-12-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-12-20**:
I'm not sure what you're asking.

**Comment by [StanSmooth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32748/stansmooth/) on 2017-12-20**:
Sorry if i'm not clear. Someone told me, it was better to have a file supposed to collect and send message on topic, and other files suposed to process the differents algorithm we use. My question is : how do we transfer data from those different files

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-20**:
Usually, a node subscribes to the topics that it needs, processes the data, and publishes data if need be.

**Comment by [StanSmooth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32748/stansmooth/) on 2017-12-21**:
Yes, but will it do it on the same file ? (for instance is it possible to have multiple files per nodes ?)
I'm finding a lot of examples of basic suscriber and publisher on the net, but nothing with a real processing. Do you have some examples ?

**Comment by [StanSmooth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32748/stansmooth/) on 2017-12-21**:
Moreover, is there any advice to implement a ros node, in object-oriented aspect ?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-21**:
What do you mean by

> multiple files per nodes

? Are you asking if you can have multiple nodes per file (like a *.py or *.cpp file)?

**Comment by [StanSmooth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32748/stansmooth/) on 2017-12-21**:
No. I know this is possible. What i'm asking is explanations (or examples) on how these nodes with multiples files are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you have heard wrong. You shouldn't need more than one .cpp file to fully describe a node. Most of the time when I'm making a new node, I actually go to the [simple tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) and use it as a template.

When you do have a very complex node, it is sometimes better to do everything as a class, it is still all in one .cpp file though. [Here are some pointers](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/UsingClassMethodsAsCallbacks) on doing that.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2017-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1